# Is there a way to see the progress of an audio download in Howler.js?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, howler.js

I'm using howler.js to play audio on my website, but because I am downloading audio through direct links there are differing load times depending on the length of the audio. I was wondering if there was a way to see how much of the file has been downloaded and display it to the user so that they know an approximate time it would take for it to finish loading. An example of how I am downloading audio is shown below.

```
   lvlHowlWEB[eps] = new Howl({

      src:["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hb7gw9zqvdptdzq/Potat2k18.mp3?dl=0"],
      html5: false,

   });
```

(Note: Audio will not begin playback until after it has loaded completely. I am just looking to see if there's a way to view how much longer it will take to be completely downloaded)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any luck with the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a ServiceWorker to intercept the HTTP requests and show progress updates as they download.  https://fetch-progress.anthum.com/

Alternatively, you could use `fetch()` and show download progress, then convert the downloaded data into a `Blob` for [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), which could then be used for Howler's `src` property.